# Retrieve Access Token ID from Auth 0

Tags: angular, spring-boot, single-sign-on, auth0, auth0-connection

I am trying to implement login with SSO functionality using Auth0, My server is with Spring Boot and my frontend is on Angular. Currently I have created a new application on Auth0 platform as single web page and added the necessary configs on my angular app (client_id, domain and redirect_uri). When clicking log in with sso the auth0 page opens the user logs in and then a response is returned with callback url containing code and state.

I am using  `this.auth.loginWithRedirect()` method of `AuthService` from `@auth0/auth0-angular` library, after i recieve the code and state i tried to send these two on spring boot application and have an api call to retrieve access token

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://mydomain.auth0.com/oauth/token");        
        JSONObject requestBody = new JSONObject();
        requestBody.put("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        requestBody.put("client_id", "***************************************");
        requestBody.put("client_secret", "**************************************");
        requestBody.put("code", code);
        requestBody.put("redirect_uri", "http://localhost:4200"); 

        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(requestBody.toString());
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();`
```

This http call constantly returns me invalid authorization code even though I am sure the code is exactly how it was returned from the callback URL on front end and also the client_id, client_secret and redirect_uri are the same as the ones on auth0 platform.

DO you have any idea what is wrong here? And also should i create a new Application/Api on AUth0 platform for spring boot application in order to communicate or is there anything else missing.

I am trying to get access token via HTTP call after i have retrieved code and state from call back URL from auth0 when trying to login but i constantly get invalid authorization code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you are using (Angular configured as a "public" OAuth2 client) is now discouraged. According to the [Spring Security team latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390), you should be using "confidential" OAuth2 clients.

An option I use is to configure `spring-cloud-gateway` with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` and the `TokenRelay=` filter between your Angular app and Spring resource server. I wrote a tutorial for that [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff#implementing-the-backend-for-frontend-pattern-with-spring-cloud-gateway) (and it works with Auth0 as you can see [here](https://bff.demo.c4-soft.com/ui/)).